# Multiple "conditions" for CSS wildcard selectors in Selenium

Tags: java, css, selenium, wildcard

I have multiple CSS webelements whose ids have the following form:

```
cell_[number]-button_[number]
```

I want to select ALL such webelements by asking Selenium to find all elements that start with *cell* and contain *button*:

```java
var elements = Util.driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[id^='cell_'] and [id*='button']"));
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Running this code returns a list with zero elements, so something is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
"[id^='cell_'][id*='button']".
```